# How does density of a set relate to Riemann integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

"A set $A$ which is a subset of $[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$ iff every open interval that intersects $[0,1]$ contains a point of $A$. Suppose $f$ maps $[0,1]$ on to $\mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ within $A$ with $A$ dense in $[0,1]$. Show that $\int_0^1f(x)\mathop{dx} = 0.$" Can someone explain how the density plays into this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question in the title is quite different from the question in the text: the latter has nothing to do with Riemann **integrability** but rather asks why the Riemann integral of a certain integrable function equals $0$. But one can ask: under which conditions is a function $f$ Riemann integrable if it vanishes on a dense set $A$? Well, since every $x$ for which $f(x)\ne 0$ is a point of discontinuity it is necessary for $f$ to be Riemann integrable that $\{x\mid f(x)\ne 0\}$ be a Lebesgue zero set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_0^1f(x)dx=c>0$; then there exists a partition $0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots <x_n=1$ such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})>c/2$$
where $m_i=\inf \{f(x)\mid x\in (x_{i-1},x_i)\}$. It follows that at least one $m_i$ must be bigger than $0$, hence $f(x)\ge m_i>0$ for every $x\in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$ --- this contradicts the assumption since $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ contains an element of $A$. If the integral would happen to be smaller than $0$ you can do the same with an upper sum.

So, density comes into play since the Riemann integral can be approximated by lower und upper sums.